# ASP.NET mvc zero to many relationship-dropdownlist default null-

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc @ visual studio community 2015.
I have 2 models (model A, model B) and I have them linked using foreign key.
Model A references B using

```
public virtual List<A> A_nav_prop { get; set; }
```

and Model B references A using

```
public int? AID { get; set; }
public virtual A A { get; set; }
```

Then I create the controllers(and automatically the views) using the entity framework.

When I run the Create View of B, I get a dropdownlist, which shows all the values of model A.

THE PROBLEM is that the dropdownlist always shows the values of modelB.
I want to be able to create A without being compulsory to select somthing from the dropdownlist.

Thank you

Comment: Then just use an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor``2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,``1}},System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable{System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem},System.String%29) of `DropDownListFor()` that accepts an `optionLabel` (`null` value)

Answer (score 0):

Per what Stephen Muecke stated... since you don't want to feel like you **have** to choose an option from the ddl.

If in your controller, your dropdownlist is stuffed into a `ViewBag` you can use this in your view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AID, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("AID",null,"-- None --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

or you can use this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AID, new SelectList(Model.AID, "Value", "Text"), "-- None --", new { @class = "nameSelecter" })
```

Comment: In this case, the label option should probably be `"None"` rather than `"-- Select Label --"`